# pass data from tableviewcontroller to another tableviewcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, textfield

I have a form I am creating

this form gets filled with textfields the user inputs. After answering all the questions a button pops up to save.

I am having a problem making this tableviewcontroller to pass the data to a new tableviewcontroller. I'm stuck and not sure how to go about this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var saveBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var firstNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var middleNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var aptNumField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var zipField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneOneField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneTwoField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var allergiesField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var DobField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sexField: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hospitalField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var doctorField: UITextField!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Notifications to push datepicker
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .saveDateTime, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            let dateVc = notification.object as! DatePopupViewController
            self.DobField.text = dateVc.formattedDate
        }

        //Notifications to push genderpicker
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .saveGender, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
            let genderVc = notification.object as! GenderPopupViewController
            self.sexField.text = genderVc.selectedGender
        }

                updateWidthsForLabels(labels: labels)
    }

    //Save Button Function
    func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == firstNameField || textField == lastNameField || textField == middleNameField || textField == addressField || textField == lastNameField || textField == cityField || textField == cityField || textField == stateField || textField == zipField || textField == phoneOneField || textField == phoneTwoField || textField == allergiesField {

            saveBtn.isHidden = true
        } else {
            saveBtn.isHidden = false
        }
    }

  @IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {


        performSegue(withIdentifier: "saveFirstPageSegue", sender: self)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about starting creating a model:

Form.swift

```
struct Form {
    var firstname: String?
    var middlename: String?
   ....
    var doctor: String?

    init(firstname: String, middlename: String, ..., doctor: String) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.middlename = middlename
        ...
        self.doctor = doctor
    }

}
```

now you can create this form instance when saving and pushing the data to the new VC:

yourCurrentForm.swift

```
@IBAction func saveBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let formData = Form(firstname: firstNameField.text, middlename: middleNameField.text, ..., doctor: doctorField.text)
    let newVC = myNewViewController()
    newVC.form = formData
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)
}
```

NewViewController.swift

```
class myNewViewController: UIViewController {

    var form: Form?

    .....

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the repo: https://github.com/FlorianLdt/LFEasyDelegate

If you have some question just ask me

Hope it helps.

Comment: would this be something I put above the class in the same tableviewcontroller or should I start a new cocoa touch class and make it a universal code

Comment: that actually makes more sense to me. Couple quick questions. I think it is working but how do I make that info pull into a tableView. in the order it fills it?

Comment: may I have a look at the new tableView that you want those info to be added ?

Comment: okay I re uploaded photos above. Pic 1 is the whole layout so far. Second pic is the form pulled from the first row of pic 3. after form is filled I would rather them hit a save button and take you back to pic 3. then once all row forms are filled out a button called print would then appear. which would take all data from all the forms and place it in the pic 4 tableview. I thought this was a little easier then it actually is. tableViews are not easy for me, but everything I do I learn more.

Comment: So the flow is: green screen -> form -> green screen again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162713/discussion-between-florian-l-and-blue-moose).

Comment: repo added. If you need more tell me

Answer (score 0):

**First Option - Structs - Preferred**

Make use of Structs :

```
struct Manager
{
 static var value : String = ""
}
```

Noe Update value of that function by just calling

```
Manager.value = "newValue"
```

Access that value anywhere Assign it to other Variables

```
let newStr : String = Manager.value
```

**Second Option - AppDelegate - Not ideal**

Create new object in AppDelegate

[image]

Now create a new object to access appDelegate

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Access Value and update as below

```
appDel.Frequency = 1.0
```

**Third Option - NSObjectClass**

Create a new NSObject class as below

[image]

//Instance created when NSObject class is first time loaded in memory stack

```
static let shared = wrapperClass()
```

//Create a value to access Globally in Object class

```
var newValueInClass : String = ""
```

Now time to access that created Object

```
wrapperClass.shared.newValueInClass = "iosGeek"
```

Now Anywhere write this Line

```
print(wrapperClass.shared.newValueInClass)
```

Console Output

[image]

**Better to use struct classes to manage data globally**

Comment: sure, If you face any issues in any declared three options just ask